# Passing postgresql parameter keywords via RPostgreSQL

Tags: r, postgresql, keep-alive, rpostgresql

I would like to pass some [parameter keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS) (specifically `keepalives`, `keepalives_idle`, `keepalives_count` , or `connect_timeout`) using the R package RPostgreQSL to connect to my DB.
I have searched the [docs](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RPostgreSQL/RPostgreSQL.pdf) and stackoverflow for an implementation, but haven't found a solution.

Is there a way to pass these parameter keywords using RPostgresSQL?

What I have tried:

1. Through the dbConnect function as additional arguments

```
conn <- RPostgreSQL::dbConnect(driver,
                               host = Sys.getenv("DBHOST"),
                               dbname = Sys.getenv("DBNAME"),
                               user = Sys.getenv("DBUSER"),
                               password = Sys.getenv("DBPASSWORD"),
                               port = Sys.getenv("DBPORT"),
                               # Parameter Keywords
                               connect_timeout = 2, 
                               keepalives = 0,
                               keepalives_idle = 0, 
                               keepalives_count = 1, 

)
```

This results in:

```
Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  unused arguments (connect_timeout = 2, keepalives = 0, keepalives_idle = 0, keepalives_count = 1)
```

2. As additional command line options:

```
conn <- RPostgreSQL::dbConnect(driver,
                               host = Sys.getenv("DBHOST"),
                               dbname = Sys.getenv("DBNAME"),
                               user = Sys.getenv("DBUSER"),
                               password = Sys.getenv("DBPASSWORD"),
                               port = Sys.getenv("DBPORT"),
                               options = "-c connect_timeout=2"
)
```

This results in:

```
Error in postgresqlNewConnection(drv, ...) : 
  RPosgreSQL error: could not connect <omitted>@<omitted>:<omitted> on dbname "<omitted>" FATAL:  unrecognized configuration parameter "connect_timeout"
```

3. Through the dbSendQuery function:

```
RPostgreSQL::dbSendQuery(conn, "SET statement_timeout to 1; SET connect_timeout to 2 ")
```

This results in

```
Error in postgresqlExecStatement(conn, statement, ...) : 
  RPosgreSQL error: could not Retrieve the result : ERROR:  unrecognized configuration parameter "connect_timeout"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR: I think RPostgreQSL does not support these connection parameters right now.

The [R doc](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RPostgreSQL/RPostgreSQL.pdf) for dbConnect-methods says

> options Command-line options to be sent to the server.

- I think it correspond to the options parameter in the [list of parameter keywords](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS):

> options Specifies command-line options to send to the server at
> connection start. For example, setting this to -c geqo=off sets the
> session's value of the geqo parameter to off. Spaces within this
> string are considered to separate command-line arguments, unless
> escaped with a backslash (); write \ to represent a literal
> backslash. For a detailed discussion of the available options, consult
> Chapter 20.

- I tried a few options from [Chapter 20](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config.html), and the server does accept these parameters. E.g.

```
    conn <- RPostgreSQL::dbConnect(driver,
                                   host = Sys.getenv("DBHOST"),
                                   dbname = Sys.getenv("DBNAME"),
                                   user = Sys.getenv("DBUSER"),                               
                                   password = Sys.getenv("DBPASSWORD"),
                                   port = Sys.getenv("DBPORT"),
                                   options="-c client_min_messages=error"
    )
```

But the parameters you want to use, e.g. `connect_timeout`, are not part of [chapter 20](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/runtime-config.html) (server options). Instead, they are connection parameters parallel to the `options` parameter. My hunch is that RPostgreQSL does not support them right now.

Comment: Great answer, thanks! Confirming I'm seeing the same behaviour with Chapter 20 args working, but not those listed in the parameter keywords with the exception of options. I found this R package that does support passing arguments from the list of parameter keywords directly to the `dbConnect` call. https://github.com/r-dbi/RPostgres